# Get Distinct data from array in php

Tags: php

I have duplicate date data in my array like this

```
$data { 
       2016-07-21,
       2016-07-22,
       2016-07-23,
       2016-07-21,
       2016-07-22,
       2016-07-23
       }
```

In MySql syntact I just put DISTINCT in query so that date will not duplicated, how can I "DISTINCT" data in PHP with this case ?

Comment: `array_unique()` ..

Comment: accepting the correct answer will help to future visitors

Answer (score 2):

`array_unique()` — Removes duplicate values from an array.

Please refer : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 0):

In php, you can use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) method for removing duplication.

```
<?php
$data = [ 
       '2016-07-21',
       '2016-07-22',
       '2016-07-23',
       '2016-07-21',
       '2016-07-22',
       '2016-07-23'
       ];

print_r(array_unique($data));
?>
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/677027)**

Answer (score 0):

> Simply run your Array through `array_unique()` and You'd get Unique Values like so:

```
<?php


    $data   =[
        '2016-07-21',
        '2016-07-22',
        '2016-07-23',
        '2016-07-21',
        '2016-07-22',
        '2016-07-23',
       ];

    $uniqueData = array_unique($data);

    var_dump($uniqueData);
    // YIELDS::
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '2016-07-21' (length=10)
      1 => string '2016-07-22' (length=10)
      2 => string '2016-07-23' (length=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get DISTINCT data from array using "array_unique() Function"
For Example,

```
<?php $a=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"red"); print_r(array_unique($a));?>
```